# Datetime format in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, datetime, nvarchar

I'm trying to convert a nvarchar to datetime like that:

```
DECLARE @Schedule nvarchar (255) = '12/16/2015 7:51 PM'
DECLARE @Datetime DATETIME
DECLARE @NormalFormatDateTime VARCHAR(MAX)

set @NormalFormatDateTime =(select SUBSTRING(@Schedule,0,3) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Schedule,4,2)  + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Schedule,7,4) +  ' ' + SUBSTRING(@Schedule,12,1) +':'+SUBSTRING(@Schedule,14,2))

SET @Datetime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @NormalFormatDateTime),103) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, @NormalFormatDateTime),108)
```

I need to insert the `@Datetime` value as Datetime type in a row. I don't get to convert the received value as datetime. I don't know what more to do.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it work ok if you do just convert(datetime, '12/16/2015 7:51 PM', 101)?

Comment: what version of sql server? new features were added for this to 2014

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I think it is `2012`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why why you need conversion here, When your column is of `Datetime` type you can directly insert without any conversion.

Your input is in valid `datetime` format

```
DECLARE @Schedule nvarchar (255) = '12/16/2015 7:51 PM'
DECLARE @Datetime DATETIME

set @Datetime = '12/16/2015 7:51 PM'

select @Datetime
```

- [**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6302)

Answer (score 0):

You can user `CAST` to convert the data type:

```
DECLARE @Schedule nvarchar (255) = '12/16/2015 7:51 PM'
DECLARE @Datetime DATETIME

SET @DateTime = CAST(@Schedule AS datetime)

IF ISDATE(@DateTime) = 1
    PRINT 'VALID'
ELSE
    PRINT 'INVALID';
```

This will give you a valid `DATETIME` field